# jquery disable by class

Tags: jquery

```
<li style="display: block;" class="selectlist-item">fsdafkds</li>
```

how can i disable a controller by class by jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your question isn't clear; you can't disable non-form field elements.*

But if you want to select an element based on its class, here is how you can do that:

```
$('.selectlist-item')
```

Notice the `dot` before class name. This is similar to CSS actually.

**More Info:**

- [jQuery Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide it using jQuery:

```
$('.classname').hide();
```

The `.` is the class-selector. Same as in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use to disable or re-enable a control:

```
function handleControlDisplay(className, foundCount, checked) {



    var button = jQuery(className);



    if (foundCount > 0 && foundCount == checked) {

        // enable

        button.removeAttr("disabled");

    }

    else {

        // set the disabled attribute

        button.attr("disabled", "true");

    };

}
```